# Undo tablespace is growing after oracle version updated from 11.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.4

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-administration

I have recently upgraded the oracle database from 11.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.4 in RAC environment. Installation was successful and i checked logs on both instances. Services were fine untill Ora 30036 resulted due to undotablespace. I got following in spfile

```
*undo_retention =108000
node11.undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
node12.undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS2'
```

I have following long running queries

```
1. EMD_MAINTENANCE.EXECUTE_EM_DBMS_JOB_PROCS()
2. #This query is for AWR auto workload repository
   select result_key_value from mgmt_policy_assoc_eval_details........ 
   ( select column_value from table cast ...........)
```

Undotablespace 2 is growing at the rate of 1700MB / hours. I am afraid that I'll ran short of space. I have following questions in my mind:-

Q1. What could be maximum undotablespace for an oracle 11.2.0.4 running in RAC?

Q2. Why retention period is specified for 30hours?

Q3. Why the tablespace2 is growing too fast?

Q4. What could be possible workaround?

It is important to highlight that we have resumed services after few days due to planned upgrade. I have stopped Enterprise manager console as well as its eating a lot of space. SysAux is at 99%.

Answer (score 1):

Q1. What could be maximum undotablespace for an oracle 11.2.0.4 running in RAC?

- please refer to https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/REFRN/limits002.htm#REFRN0042 for details.

Q2. Why retention period is specified for 30hours?

- is before upgrade, the pramater value never changed? it is configured by manual.

Q3. Why the tablespace2 is growing too fast?

- please check if there is long running transaction from gv$transaction or x$ktuxe which consume too many undo blocks. if not, maybe the undo rentention need reduce.

Q4. What could be possible workaround?

- advice that do not set the undo datafile autoextend is on avoid the disk space oom. and refer to Q3. i think the buiness is also changed after upgrade.

Comment: During troubleshooting I found following query and job. 1st query is for AWR auto workload repository like.

    select result_key_value from mgmt_policy_assoc_eval_details  ( 
    select column_value from table cast )
   #select * from TABLE ( select cast( )) -- VARRAY->Nested Table 
   problem


   EMD_MAINTENANCE.EXECUTE_EM_DBMS_JOB_PROCS()

On further investigation I found that enterprise manager is not properly configured and I had to configure it again.